# env vars in cronjobs in Docker

Tags: docker, cron

I want to run cronjobs in a docker container that need access to the docker environment variables. I can get the env vars in a file by doing this:

```
printenv | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/export \1/g' > /root/project_env.sh
```

and then source that file, but I can't figure out how to automatically run that shell command to get the project_env.sh file. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you source it in your cron job command?

Comment: The question is how to automaticity generate the file

Comment: I was able to create it in the run.sh file.